# Java S3 getObjectContent

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, inputstream

I am trying to use this example from the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html) to get a file from S3.

The file I am trying to read from S3 is a binary file. I need the InputStream from s3object.getObjectContent() to work with it in [another framework](http://auxilii.com/msgparser/). If I am trying to save the S3ObjectInputStream I receive the following error:

```
WARNING: Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use.
```

My code is actually pretty easy:

```
public String handleRequest(S3Event event, Context context) {
    context.getLogger().log("Received event: " + event.toJson());

    // Get the object from the evØent and show its content type
    String bucket = event.getRecords().get(0).getS3().getBucket().getName();
    String key = event.getRecords().get(0).getS3().getObject().getKey();

    try (S3Object response = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket, key))) {
        Long filesize = response.getObjectMetadata().getContentLength();
        System.out.println("File size is: " + filesize);
        S3ObjectInputStream s3is = response.getObjectContent();

        MsgParser msgp = new MsgParser();
        Message msg = msgp.parseMsg(s3is);
        String fromEmail = msg.getFromEmail();
        String fromName = msg.getFromName();
        String subject = msg.getSubject();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to get file from S3 with reason: " + e);
    }

    return "";
}
```

What is my error here?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the memory on your lambda?

Comment: I think this might actually be a known bug: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1211

Comment: @JarredOlson: Configured are 512MB and used not even 100MB

Comment: I used another [framework](https://github.com/ram-sharma-6453/email-mime-parser) and this worked fine.